# ANTLR replace tokens in a recursive manner

Tags: java, antlr, antlr3, antlrworks

I have the following grammar:

```
rule: q=QualifiedName {System.out.println($q.text);};

QualifiedName
   :   
        i=Identifier { $i.setText($i.text + "_");}
        ('[' (QualifiedName+ | Integer)? ']')*
   ;


Integer
    : Digit Digit*
    ;

fragment
Digit 
    : '0'..'9'
    ;

fragment
Identifier
    :   (   '_'
        |   '$'
        |   ('a'..'z' | 'A'..'Z')
        )
        ('a'..'z' | 'A'..'Z' | '0'..'9' | '_' | '$')*
    ;
```

and the code from Java:

```
ANTLRStringStream stream = new ANTLRStringStream("array1[array2[array3[index]]]");
TestLexer lexer = new TestLexer(stream);
CommonTokenStream tokens = new TokenRewriteStream(lexer);
TestParser parser = new TestParser(tokens);
try {
    parser.rule();
} catch (RecognitionException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

For the input: `array1[array2[array3[index]]]`, i want to modify each identifier. I was expecting to see the output: `array1_[array_2[array3_[index_]]]`, but the output was the same as the input.

So the question is: why the `setText()` method doesn't work here?

**EDIT:**

I modified Bart's answer in the following way:

```
rule: q=qualifiedName {System.out.println($q.modified);};

qualifiedName returns [String modified]
   :   
        Identifier
        ('[' (qualifiedName+ | Integer)? ']')*
        {
            $modified = $text + "_";
        }
   ;

Identifier
    :   (   '_'
        |   '$'
        |   ('a'..'z' | 'A'..'Z')
        )
        ('a'..'z' | 'A'..'Z' | '0'..'9' | '_' | '$')*
    ;

Integer
    : Digit Digit*
    ;

fragment
Digit 
    : '0'..'9'
    ;
```

I want to modify each token matched by the rule `qualifiedName`. I tried the code above, and for the input `array1[array2[array3[index]]]` i was expecting to see the output `array1[array2[array3[index_]_]_]_`, but instead only the last token was modified: `array1[array2[array3[index]]]_`.

How can i solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can only use `setText(...)` once a token is created. You're recursively calling this token ***and*** setting some other text, which won't work. You'll need to create a parser rule out of `QualifiedName` instead of a lexer rule, and remove the `fragment` before `Identifier`.

```
rule: q=qualifiedName {System.out.println($q.text);};

qualifiedName
   :   
        i=Identifier { $i.setText($i.text + "_");}
        ('[' (qualifiedName+ | Integer)? ']')*
   ;

Identifier
    :   (   '_'
        |   '$'
        |   ('a'..'z' | 'A'..'Z')
        )
        ('a'..'z' | 'A'..'Z' | '0'..'9' | '_' | '$')*
    ;

Integer
    : Digit Digit*
    ;

fragment
Digit 
    : '0'..'9'
    ;
```

Now, it *will* print: `array1_[array2_[array3_[index_]]]` on the console.

### EDIT

I have no idea why you'd want to do that, but it seems you're simply trying to rewrite `]` into `]_`, which can be done in the same way as I showed above:

```
qualifiedName
   :   
        Identifier
        ('[' (qualifiedName+ | Integer)? t=']' {$t.setText("]_");} )*
   ;
```

Comment: Thank you Bart. This is exactly what i tried right before you answered and it worked. I have one more question: in the parser, you can access the text matched by a rule with $text. Can this text be modified?

Comment: @user1019710, no, only a token's text can be modified. Calling `$text` from a parser rule simply iterates over all tokens in this rule and glues together all the token's text.

Comment: Please take a look at my **EDIT** above. I'm sure you know the answer. Thank you very much.